# Python Selenium Chrome Driver Payload

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, driver, payload

I am trying to instrument Chrome and the driver needs to include a payload:

```
    payload={
      'response_type':   'code',
      'redirect_uri':    config.redirect_uri,
      'client_id':       client_code,
    }

   
    #
    ## Print chrome_options
    # print(get_chrome_options())

    #
    ## Open browser window to authenticate using User ID and Password
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(config.chrome_driver_path, options=self.get_chrome_options(), params=payload)
```

This is generating an error:

```
 got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'
```

Is it possible to send a payload with the driver?

Comment: WebDriver does not accept any form of payload, why are you even trying to pass a url and ID to the WebDriver instance.

Comment: First of all, @Jared is correct. Second, If you are trying to send that payload with **all** the requests webdriver makes, I. don'tt hink you can do that really. You can make whatever requests you want from inside the tests but otherwise

Answer (score 0):

@jared - I was doing this out of ignorance. I managed to solve the issue by using query strings/parameters:

```
url_encoded_client_code = urllib.parse.quote(client_code)

url_with_qstrings = "https://url?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&client_id=url_encoded_client_code"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(config.chrome_driver_path, options=self.get_chrome_options())

browser.get(url_with_qstrings)
```